# Function overloading and confusion between double and long

Tags: c++

I expected this simple code to compile:

```
void Foo(long a, long);
void Foo(long a, double b);

int main()
{
  Foo(1, 2);
  Foo(1, 2.0);
}
```

Compiler output:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:8:11: error: call of overloaded ‘Foo(int, int)’ is ambiguous
   Foo(1, 2);
           ^
prog.cpp:3:6: note: candidate: void Foo(long int, long int)
 void Foo(long a, long);
      ^~~
prog.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: void Foo(long int, double)
 void Foo(long a, double b);
      ^~~
```

I don't understand why the call is ambigous. For me `Foo(unsigned long a, unsigned long)` is clearly a closer match than `void Foo(unsigned long a, double b)` for `Foo(1, 2)`.

But if I replace `long` by `int` it compiles:

```
void Foo(int a, int);
void Foo(int a, double b);

int main()
{
  Foo(1, 2);
  Foo(1, 2.0);
}
```

I'm really lost here.

Comment: Your code doesn't match the error messages and your words.

Comment: @S.M. yes it does, [see here](https://www.ideone.com/39i5e1)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Ideone's error messages don't show `unsigned`.

Comment: @S.M. Touche. Luckily for me my answer still applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1` and `2` are literals of type `int`, and `2.0` is a `double`.

So neither overload is an exact match for your types, they are ranked similarly for the purposes of overload resolution, so the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic. (Note that `int` and `long` must be different types even if they have the same size and complementing scheme.)

You could fix with `Foo(1L, 2L);`.

Comment: OK, so I just somewhat misunderstood the overload lookup system.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Fortunately the C++ one is beautifully consistent. If you want to dispose of your lunch quickly, have a look at the Java one!